# Disable error : Unexpected end of file looking for </form> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I need to disable error "Unexpected end of file looking for  tag." when precompiling website project in Visual Studio 2013. The problem cannot be fixed in code, so I just need to disable it, or just compile App_Data folder to reference it from another project.

Comment: Why you are trying to disable error instead of solving it?

Comment: This is a good example of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about your thought up solution instead of describing the real issue.